# Form ON CURRENT Event - Access 2013

Tags: if-statement, textbox

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

   If Nz(Me!CompName, "") = "" Then
      Me!CompName.Locked = False

   Else
    If (txtName = "Maxie") Then
        Me!CompName.Locked = False
        Else
        Me!CompName.Locked = True
    End If
End if
End Sub
```

CompName is a Textbox where I Enter Company Name and once there is an input the user cannot edit it Unless the user from "txtName is Maxie"
txtName is a unbound textbox which acquire the Username from the Login Form.

The Problem is even the txtName Contain "Maxie" the CompName textbox is still locked.

Please help me solve this.

By the way I use this code under ON CURRENT Event.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the modified code

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

Me.Refresh
Dim UserAdmin As String
UserAdmin = "Maxie"

    If Nz(Me!CompName, "") = "" Then
    Me!CompName.Locked = False
    Me.Refresh
    Else
        If (txtName.Value = UserAdmin) Then
             Me!CompName.Locked = False
             Me.Refresh
                Else
                    Me!CompName.Locked = True
                    Me.Refresh
                        End If
   End If
End Sub
```